# Tensor product of two ample invertible sheaves is ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Why is the tensor product of two ample invertible sheaves ample when working over a noetherian scheme $X$?

This is what I have tried:

A sheaf $L$ is said to be ample if for every coherent sheaf $F$  there exist $n_0$  such that $F\otimes L^n$ is generated by global sections for all $n\geq n_0$ .

Let $L$ and $M$ be two ample invertible sheaves and let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. $L$ is ample so there exist $n_0$ such that $F\otimes L^n$ is generated by global sections for all $n\geq n_0$. Similarly there exist $m_0$ corresponding to $M$. I don’t know how to proceed further. Please someone help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've taken the liberty of improving the formatting of your post by adding [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). As far as your question goes, what results and criteria do you know about ampleness? Do you know how it interacts with global generation, for instance?

Comment: I have just started with the ample sheaves. I only know the definition .

Comment: Do you mean that some power of ample sheaf ( in tensor sense)  is generated by global sections because we can take coherent sheaf to be ample sheaf itself?

Comment: Something like that - I've posted an answer. In the future, I'd encourage you to make a habit of posting your definitions and what sort of results you know in your question so that everyone's on the same page. You can do that here with an [edit].

Answer (score 3):

We can combine several bite-size claims to give the full result.

**Proposition 1** (Hartshorne II.7.5): Let $L$ be an invertible sheaf on a noetherian scheme $X$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $L$ is ample;
2. $L^{\otimes m}$ is ample for all $m>0$;
3. $L^{\otimes m}$ is ample for some $m>0$.

**Proof**: The implications 1 $\Rightarrow$ 2 $\Rightarrow$ 3 are all trivial, so we concentrate on 3 $\Rightarrow$ 1. Given a coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$ and an integer $0\leq a<m$, by the definition of ampleness we have that there exists some $n_a>0$ so that for all $n\geq n_a$, $(F\otimes L^{\otimes a})\otimes(L^{\otimes m})^{\otimes n}$ is generated by global sections. Taking $N=m\cdot\max_a(n_a)$, we have that $F\otimes L^{\otimes n}$ is generated by global sections for all $n\geq N$, and $L$ is ample. $\blacksquare$

**Proposition 2**: If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are two sheaves that are generated by a finite number of global sections, then their tensor product $M_1\otimes M_2$ is.

**Proof**: Consider the surjective composite map $\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n_1}\otimes \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n_2}\to \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n_1}\otimes M_2\to  M_1\otimes M_2$. $\blacksquare$

**Proposition 3**: If $L$ is an ample invertible sheaf and $M$ is an invertible sheaf generated by global sections, then $L\otimes M$ is ample.

**Proof**: If $F$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf so that $F\otimes L^n$ is generated by global sections, then $F\otimes L^{\otimes n}\otimes M^{\otimes n} \cong F\otimes (L\otimes M)^{\otimes n}$ is generated by global sections. $\blacksquare$

**Proposition 4**: If $L$ and $M$ are ample invertible sheaves on a noetherian scheme $X$, then $L\otimes M$ is ample.

**Proof**: Find an $n>0$ so that $L\otimes M^{\otimes n}$ is globally generated by the definition of ampleness. Then $L^{\otimes n-1}\otimes (L\otimes M^{\otimes n}) \cong L^{\otimes n}\otimes M^{\otimes n}\cong (L\otimes M)^{\otimes n}$ is ample by proposition 3, as $L^{\otimes n-1}$ is ample by proposition 1 and $L\otimes M^{\otimes n}$ is globally generated. As a sheaf is ample iff some tensor power is by proposition 1, we're done. $\blacksquare$